# TikZ: How can an ellipse callout be mirrored?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, positioning, callout

I am using TikZ in Beamer and would like to mirror an ellipse callout as part of a tikz picture such that it points to the given node.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.callouts}
    
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node(st){Something};
\node(ec)[ellipse callout, above right=of st, draw=black]{Comment};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

  
\end{document}
```

[image: ellipse callout and node]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.callouts}
    
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node(st){Something};
\node(ec)[
  ellipse callout, 
  above right=of st, 
  draw=black,
  callout relative pointer={(-1,-1)}
  ]{Comment};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node(st){Something};
\node(ec)[
  ellipse callout, 
  above right=of st, 
  draw=black,
  callout absolute pointer={(st.north east)}
  ]{Comment};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

  
\end{document}
```

[image]